# What is the best way to print a Staircase using Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I'm writing a method to print a staircase, it would be like

```
     #
    ##
   ###
  ####
 #####
######
```

This is a staircase of 6 rows. So I come up with this code:

```
def print_staircase(num_rows)
  for i in (1..num_rows)
    puts ' ' * (num_rows-i) + '#' * i
  end
end

print_staircase(6)
=>
     #
    ##
   ###
  ####
 #####
######
```

So it works, but I think this is kind of inefficient, any better solution?

Because if num_rows is large, so we will construct the result like `' ' * (n-i) + '#' * i` every time, I think this is not a good idea!

Comment: Why do you think it's a hack?

Comment: @JanDvorak Sorry, I mean inefficient actually, check my update!

Comment: I don't think that's inefficient. Also, you don't really need performance in this case.

Comment: do you read the question carefully :D, every time constructing a new string but it doesn't have much change, that is what I mean :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create an initial string once and set a `#` on each iteration:

```
def print_staircase(num_rows)
  str = ' ' * num_rows
  1.upto(num_rows) do |i|
    str[-i] = '#'
    puts str
  end
end
```

This re-uses `str` instead of creating a new string instance every time.

But usually, you would see something like this:

```
def print_staircase(num_rows)
  1.upto(num_rows) { |i| puts ('#' * i).rjust(num_rows) }
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a variable equalling empty string at first. Then with a cycle always add a '#' to it and display it. That would save the current value after each iteration and you will need to add a single '#' to the string instead of recalculating it from scratch in each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this, yours is one solution and it seems fine to me. If implemented two additional solutions and a benchmark. Your solution was the fastest of those three (microbenchmark disclaimer applies, especially because I do IO with `puts`/`print`).

```
def staircase_0(size)
  string = ' ' * (size - 1) + '#' * size
  size.times do |offset|
    puts string[offset...(offset + size)]
  end
end

def staircase_1(size)
  prefix = ' ' * (size - 1)
  postfix = '#'
  size.times do
    print prefix
    puts postfix
    prefix = prefix[1..-1]
    postfix += '#'
  end
end


def staircase_2(num_rows)
  for i in (1..num_rows)
    puts ' ' * (num_rows-i) + '#' * i
  end
end


require 'benchmark/ips'

Benchmark.ips do |x|
  x.report('_0') do
    staircase_0(6)
  end
  x.report('_1') do
    staircase_1(6)
  end
  x.report('_2') do
    staircase_2(6)
  end
  x.compare!
end
```

And the results:

```
Comparison:
                  _2:    35649.0 i/s
                  _0:    29716.3 i/s - 1.20x slower
                  _1:    25848.2 i/s - 1.38x slower
```

Please be aware that because of the IO the results might differ a lot. IO is slow (so it has more weight that your algorithm and string concatenation). It is also not predictable and can differ from run to run. A more efficient (in terms of runtime) solution might therefore be to output just one string:

```
def staircase_3(size)
  string = ''
  size.times do |index|
    string += ' ' * (size - index - 1) + '#' * (index + 1) + "\n"
  end
  puts string
end
```

And indeed when I run the benchmarks it is faster:

```
Comparison:
                  _3:    52923.7 i/s
                  _0:    36377.7 i/s - 1.45x slower
                  _2:    33508.7 i/s - 1.58x slower
                  _1:    25991.6 i/s - 2.04x slower
```

Also note that in this run your version of the algorithm (`staircase_2`) is slower than `staircase_0` ...which is because of IO. But in all my runs `staircase_3` was fastest.

Comment: @HieuPham i've updated my answer to add another solution.

Comment: Thanks, I also check your solution, great contribution man, I really appreciate this :)

Comment: How about compare to @Stefan solution?

Comment: @pascalbetz and you should run the benchmark with different staircase heights, e.g. 10, 100 and 1000.

Comment: @Stefan well, it was just to show that it is hard to benchmark because of the IO. If you want to benchmark the algorithm, then you probably should just build the strings and output to a StringIO instead. This should have consistent and comparable performance.

Comment: Just assign `$stdout = StringIO.new` before each test and `$stdout = STDOUT` afterwards

Comment: Yes, i know. But did not want to go that far, looks like the OP is a beginner in ruby...